# derivative of an integral in python

Tags: python

I have a function with two variables f(x,y) = x +2y, I want to integrate it with respect to x then take derivative with respect to y, then plot the results with y, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy.integrate
from scipy.misc import derivative



x = raw_input("enter x: "); x=float(x)
y = raw_input("enter y: "); y=float(y)

def f1(x,y):

  r=x+2*y
  return r
r=f1(x,y)
print "r=",r

def int(y):
    return scipy.integrate.quad(f1, 0,x,args=(y))
vint=np.vectorize(int)
ylist=np.linspace(0,y,10)
results,errs=vint(ylist)
plt.plot(ylist,results)
plt.show()


def dI(y):
   return derivative(int,y)


vdI=np.vectorize(dI)
sol,err=vdI(ylist)
plt.plot(ylist,sol)
plt.show()
```

but I got this error message:

```
 val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide complete code - there is no definition of func - most likely it returns a tuple

Comment: It is also possible that you are calling code that uses `int`, which you have redefined as `scipy.integrate.quad`, which returns a tuple